# How to set a letter limit within a digit string

Tags: regex

I tried some explanations that I read here in the forum but I could not succeed

I would like to set a limit of letters within a digit string

for example, a limit of up to three letters:

example : AAA12348
 example: 12AAA234
 example: 1234A568

Comment: This would match on strings that fail: `[A-Z][0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*[A-Z][0-9]*[A-Z]` You should probably specify which language/flavor of regex you're using to see if a better option exists.

Comment: A limit of up to three letters in a row, or three letters total?

Comment: total of three letters.  I wrote three scenarios and stayed on the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern will only allow a maximum of 3 letters within each string. It anchors at the beginning of the string and then asserts that it is not followed by four letters, separated by anything.

`^(?!.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z]).*$`

https://regex101.com/r/pQmili/2

Edit: If you also wish to disallow a set of certain other characters such as `!` and `#`, you can create an additional negative lookahead group containing a character set of those characters.

`^(?!.*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z])(?!.*[!#]).*$`

https://regex101.com/r/pQmili/3

Comment: Could you explain me about your solution?
For, I am trying to modify it, not to accept special characters such as: +, -,.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that here we wish to fail two of our inputs and pass only one of them:

```
((\D+?)\d{1,3}(\D+?))
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yfBC2O/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]